# C# adicionar controles ao meu form

Tags: c#

Como faço para adicionar dinamicamente os controles ao meu form? Durante o programa dependendo do que aconteça eu gostaria que fosse adicionado controles(button,textbox) ao meu programa.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
t1.Text = "Olá Mundo!";
this.Controls.Add(t1);
```

Vê se deu certo ^^

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado! vou adicionar outras opções default tb, vlwzao